# How do I get Aurelia to process scss

Tags: sass, aurelia

I have created a new Aurelia using the cli and setting scss for the CSS Processor and webpack for the bundler. My problem is the scss seems to be ignored and I cant work out why.

I have a file in project /src/styles/styles.scss

Inside the aurelia.json file (I have added the source property)

```
...
    "cssProcessor": {
        "id": "sass",
        "displayName": "Sass",
        "fileExtension": ".scss",
        "source": "src/**/*.scss"
      },
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you imported your scss-file in any components? I think you can make it work by adding this line to your app.ts file (or whatever startup component you are using)

> import 'app.scss';

Requiring it in the template should also work, a discussion of both methods is available here: https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/14

Comment: That link put me on the correct path but I needed to use <require from="./styles/styles.scss"></require> in my app.html instead.

Comment: Actually the import worked fine I just needed more of the relative path import 'styles/styles.scss';